# Keep getting 500 error code when query to SQL server

Tags: php, sql-server, azure

I have a SQL server host on Microsoft Azure, I tried to query some data from it on Visual Studio. It works, however, I just keep getting 500 error code when I try to query by PHP. Am I having anything wrong? Here is my code

```
try{
        $conn = new PDO ( not shown for privacy reason );
        $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        header("Content-type: plain/text");
        print($e->getMessage());
    }

    $name = $conn->quote($name);
    $pw = $conn->quote($pw);

    $account = $conn->query("SELECT [user]
                             FROM dbo.user_data
                             WHERE [user] LIKE $name AND [password] LIKE $pw");

    return $account[0];
```

Comment: there should be more in your error logs

Comment: @EpochGalaxy's answer is correct. And additionally, you can enable `display_errors` in PHP runtime, for troubleshooting, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#how-to-change-the-built-in-php-configurations for more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, 
PDO::query — Executes an SQL statement, returning a result set as a PDOStatement object.
$account[0] will result a fatal error "Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array"
So, you should do this after the code to access each row value as :

```
$account = $conn->query("SELECT [user]
                             FROM dbo.user_data
                             WHERE [user] LIKE $name AND [password] LIKE $pw");
foreach ($account as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
```

Hope this solves your problem. Thanks.